# Analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

By stereo graphic projection we know that  $|Z|>r$ is a neighbourhood of $\infty$. Now we know that polynomials are analytic in this domain which is a neighbourhood of $\infty$ and so it is analytic at $\infty$.But any non-constant polynomial has a pole at $\infty$. So what is the problem? Please someone help me.

Comment: $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $\infty$ iff $f(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at $0.$ Why? That's the defintion. So a nonconstant polynomial is never holomorphic at $\infty.$

Comment: A non constant polynomial is never analytic at infinity if we are from entire complex plane to complex plane as it is not even continuous there.

Comment: f(z) is has singularity at ∞ iff f(1/z) has same type of  singularity at 0.

Comment: If f(1/z) has a removable singularity then we can remove it and make holomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain $|z|>r$ is a punctured neighborhood of infinity : if you want to have a full neighborhood, you have to add infinity.

That being said, a polynomial map is analytic when regarded as a map from the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to itself. It evidently is not when regarded as a map from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to $\mathbb C$, since $P(\infty)$ is not even an element of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: If we are on extended complex plane  then |Z|>1 is a neighbourhood of infinity then is it true that polynomials are analytic in this neighbourhood? or still it is puncture neighourhood. Please help.

Comment: short version is, a polynomial map is analytic wherever it is defined

Comment: If we arefrom C^ to C then definitely it is defined on its domain.

Comment: a polynomial map from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to $\mathbb C$ is NOT well defined at $\infty$. however it IS as a map from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. so in the first case it is not analytic in the neighborhood of $\infty$ since it is not even defined at $\infty$, but in the second case it is well defined and analytic

Comment: Yes  if we define value of polynomial at infinity other than infinity then it is not even continuous at infinity. Is it  right?

Comment: yes you are, precisely

Comment: Thanking you for such a great help.

Comment: but there is no non constant entire function that is analytic at infinity. now non constant polynomials are analytic on Riemann sphere to itself. What is mistake?